# Shorten CSS with a lot of classes

Tags: css

Does anybody knows how to shorten CSS Code like this?

```
body.term-hmk .site-header, body.term-hmk .main-navigation ul ul, body.term-hmk .secondary-navigation ul ul, body.term-hmk .main-navigation ul.menu > li.menu-item-has-children::after, body.term-hmk .secondary-navigation ul.menu ul, body.term-hmk .main-navigation ul.menu ul, body.term-hmk .main-navigation ul.nav-menu ul {
background-color: #ffeeff}

body.term-dtq .site-header, body.term-dtq .main-navigation ul ul, body.term-dtq .secondary-navigation ul ul, body.term-dtq .main-navigation ul.menu > li.menu-item-has-children::after, body.term-dtq .secondary-navigation ul.menu ul, body.term-dtq .main-navigation ul.menu ul, body.term-dtq .main-navigation ul.nav-menu ul {
background-color: #9c9e9f !important;}
```

Unfortunatly it takes a very long time to write this for all my sites, so if there is a better solution of that, please let me know.

Comment: Shouldn't take too long using copy/paste methods.  The only way to shorten it is to get rid of unneeded selectors.  Are there selectors in there that you don't need?

Comment: Seems to me like you're almost certainly over specifying here. http://robertnyman.com/2007/10/18/dont-over-specify-your-css-code/ It's also possible you might be able to use something like LESS or SASS to dry up your stylesheets a bit.

Comment: Hit enter after every `,` in the selector list, this will make it much easier to read.

Comment: You where right Ajedi32!
I was realy over speciifying here. Cloud shoren it up with the right and only needed classes.

Answer (score 3):

Could you try using a wrapper DIV (or a span) that you assign all the stylistic stuff you want to, and then just put that div around the stuff you want styled?

eg.

```
.style1 {
  background-color: #ffeeff
}
```

and then put that around what you want to style

```
<div class=style1>
  [stuff to style]
</div>
```

This way you only have to put the div around the stuff you want to style, which is much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

If you subscribe to the philosophy that HTML should be for markup only, and not contain style information then not so much, but if you are happy to put an additional class on all of the elements you want that `background-color` property to apply to then you could have:

```
.some-class {
    background-color: #ffeeff;
}
```

Alternatively you could make the selectors more concise, do you need to have `body.term-dtq .side-header`? Could you make it more concise with a unique class name such as `.term-header`

The issue above can't be fixed easily, but you can fix it by removing the unnecessary length of the selectors.

Answer (score 0):

It now looks like this

```
.term-xx .site-header, 
.term-xx .main-navigation ul, 
.term-xx .secondary-navigation ul, 
.term-xx .widget_shopping_cart_content, 
.term-xx .site-footer {
  background-color: #ffeeff !important;
}
```

It ist much more compact now.

So there is no shortened code option for .term-xx on all those classes?

I need .term-xx because I need differnt header and footer background colors on multiple pages. So .term-xx is in the Body and secifing the individual Page.

It's a Wordpress Installation if this matters.